# How to manually bootstrap app referencing a module in a separate file

Tags: angularjs

I am manually bootstrapping my application so I can perform a cookie session check on the server and then only continue to bootstrap if the user has a valid session.

Code:

```
angular.module('ppMobi', [])
            .controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.loggedIn = true;
                $scope.foo = "Session Valid";
            });

            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
                var $http = initInjector.get("$http");
                //This will return a promise on success or failure and provided user has a valid session we can then take them to the app
                //that is manually bootstrap our app.
                return $http.get("/session/GetSession.json").then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.success) {
                        console.log("Session found!");
                        angular.bootstrap(document, ["ppMobi"]);
                    } else {
                        window.location = "/login.html";
                    }
                }, function (errorResponse) {
                    console.error("Session not found!");
                });
            });
```

This works as expected, but I would now like to move the module\controller definition into a separate file.

I have tried this already and added a script include to the file just after the main lib include, so now I have:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">



            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
                var $http = initInjector.get("$http");
                //This will return a promise on success or failure and provided user has a valid session we can then take them to the app
                //that is manually bootstrap our app.
                return $http.get("/session/GetSession.json").then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.success) {
                        console.log("Session found!");
                        angular.bootstrap(document, ["ppMobi"]);
                    } else {
                        window.location = "/login.html";
                    }
                }, function (errorResponse) {
                    console.error("Session not found!");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

app/app.js

```
angular.module('ppMobi', [])
.controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.loggedIn = true;
    $scope.foo = "Session Valid";
});
```

But it seems the ready handler on the document is no longer being caught as no $http is being made, so clearly I have broken something by doing this (no errors inc console either)

Does my approach make sense? - please advise! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have answered my own question...

I just moved the document ready handler code into my app.js, so now what I originally had in my main html file as per my first code snippet is all my app.js and the include to the file after the library include remains.

It's still working fine for me stuctured in this way